# Multiple Table delete using order by and Limit in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

When using delete statement for single table with Limit and ORDERBY its working fine

```
DELETE FROM test_users_table  ORDER BY test_users_table_cname DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Can we also achieve delete in multiple table using ORDER BY AND LIMIT option ..

Here is what I am using

```
  DELETE test_users_table, test_user_data_table FROM test_users_table 
    JOIN test_user_data_table 
    ON test_users_table.table1_id = test_user_data_table.table2_userid
    ORDER BY test_users_table.cname DESC
    LIMIT 5
```

For multiple table its throwing error

Comment: What is the error it is throwing??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/delete.html), this is the syntax for deleting from multiple tables:

```
DELETE [LOW_PRIORITY] [QUICK] [IGNORE]
tbl_name[.*] [, tbl_name[.*]] ...
FROM table_references
[WHERE where_condition]
```

Additionally it states:

> For the multiple-table syntax, DELETE deletes from each tbl_name the rows that satisfy the conditions. **In this case, ORDER BY and LIMIT cannot be used.**

Thus, you **can** delete from multiple tables. However, you cannot use the `LIMIT` keyword directly in it.

What's the assumed semantic for your query? Should the statement delete the first 5 entries from table A, table B or 5 entries from each table? This information might help to restructure your query.

Comment: can we do it through looping and using TOP

Comment: What do you mean by looping? And as far as I know, MySQL doesn't support the `TOP` keyword.

Comment: Thanks .. I really don't knew it about TOP in #mysql ...  Loop if can be done using SP